# Azure Automation Get-Azure not returning anything

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

***UPDATE TO BLOG I WROTE AFTER THIS ISSUES WAS SOLVED:***

[Click here to see my blog post on this](http://www.russellmccloy.com/2014/12/stop-azurevm-using-azure-automation.html)

**Note: confidential stuff replaced by: xxx**

**Note2: I could not get the formatting around my code blocks to work correctly so apologies for this.**

I have been working with Azure Automation.

I want to shut down using stop-AzureVM nightly and restart it in the morning to save money.

I can call get-AzureVM from my local machine using powershell ISE but when I run my powershell script in Azure Automation in the Azure portal, get-AzureVM doesn't return anything and hence, I can't get my VM and therefore stop it.

**Here is my script in my run book:**

```
workflow Stop-MyVM {

# Specify Azure Subscription Name
$subName = 'My subscription Connection'

# Connect to Azure Subscription
Connect-Azure -AzureConnectionName $subName

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName 

$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'xxx-xxxx' -Name 'xxx-xxxVM' 

Write-Output "VM NAME: $vm"

# stop code to go here when I work out why get-AzureVM is not working 
}
```

**I also have 2 assets:**
**Connection:**
[image]
**Certificate:**
[image]

**I also have another run book that I downloaded from the web to connect to Azure. This is pretty standard and is not causing the issue:**
[image]

**The line that is not working but not erroring is:**
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'xxx-xxx' -Name 'xxx-xxxVM'

**Here is the output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the job history for this job, are any error records listed?

Does it work if you just try to grab all VMs?

```
$VMs = Get-AzureVM
Write-Output $VMs
```

Also, we recommend using OrgID auth in Azure Automation, instead of certificate auth. See http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/ for more details.

Comment: You may have spelled it wrong in the runbook, its "Get-AutomationPSCredential" not "Get-AutomationPSScredential". What error do you get?

Comment: Joe, 

I didn't realised I left that posted as I found the spelling issue immediately. 

I have changed to using orgId and simplified my solution and it now works.

Another thing was that other blogs were saying to use a connection asset holding my subscription id and a PFX cert where others were just saying to use my subscription name directly.

I am currently writing a blog post regard this.
I thank you for your comments and will mark your answer as the correct one.

thanks
Russ

Comment: Thanks Russ. Yes cert auth was the old way to do it in Azure Automation, hence why old blog posts talk about that. OrgID is the way forward though.

Comment: Thanks Joe, So I still need the cert at subscription level or don't need a cert. (any cert) from the Azure machine at all now?

Comment: Don't need the cert anymore. OrgID Credential provides the secret needed to authenticate, instead of the cert. This is of course assuming you are not using cert auth anywhere else to talk to Azure.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you few things-

a.  Go to ASSET tab and add proper windows powershell credentials (simply you can use username and password, the same you use to login to azure portal).

b. Add your code in the runbook. Suppose your powershell automation credential name is StartVM and your subscription name is xxx. In this case the workflow will be-

```
   workflow StartVM
   {
    $Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name
    StartVM' Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName “xxx”
    inlineScript
      {
        Start-AzureVM -Name TestServer -ServiceName CS12345
      }
   }
```

c. After this you can schedule your runbook as per your need.

Hope this one will help you-

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/25/introducing-the-azure-automation-script-converter/
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-create-runbook-from-samples/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at last line of Connect-Azure script, $AzureConnectionName is used as subscription name to set the PS context. Is your connection name and subscription name the same ? If not can you test by running Connect-Azure with your subscription name or rename the connection asset's name to be same as your subscription name.

Comment: Thanks @Sri. If you read my comment above you will see that I was confused and have now sorted out the issue. 

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to test with a brand new Azure AD account. I was using one with which I was able to log to the Azure Portal without issue, but `Get-AzureVM` in the script with that credentials was always null.

I tried to re-created the Credentials and Runbook but at the end I just had to create a new Azure AD user and assign Co-administrator role once created.